# Broadcast Extension with ReplayKit Xamarin iOS not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios-extensions, replaykit

I'm trying to add a broadcast extension to a Xamarin iOS app but the extension is not visible when I want to start a broadcast from either in the app or the control center.

I added both a BroadcastUploadExtension as a BroadcastUpload UI Extension to the project and they are references from the main iOS project. Both extension projects target iOS 13.0+

I also created provisioning profiles for them. I use the RPSystemBroadcastPickerView with PreferredExtension but I just get 'Start recording' and not my app name/icon with start streaming.
All on the newest versions of SDK and iOS.

Comment: You can check the requirements in Container app project and Extension project [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions#creating-an-extension).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT thanks that is what I followed but no luck. It drives me nuts.

Comment: You mean the code in the Extension never work? Did you ever debug the extension and add a breakpoint to see whether the code there been hit?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT thanks. I get the feeling the the whole extension is not seen by iOS. But I have no clue how to debug this. It's not possible to list extensions in the container app right? Both the debug.writeline and breakpoints in the constructors are not hit. I think the next thing I can do is to create a small sample project with only the two extensions and to see if I've the same problem there. That project I then can share for people to have a look at.

Comment: Yes, create a small sample project and see if it works first.

Answer (score 0):

The BroadcastUIExtension project will be created automatically when you create a BroadcastUploadExtension project in VS,
you can open the info.plist in both projects and double-check the `NSExtension` key.

The value of the `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` for BroadcastUploadExtension project is written as **com.apple.broadcast-services** by default
and should be **com.apple.broadcast-services-upload**

The value of the `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` for BroadcastUIExtension project is written as **com.apple.broadcast-services** by default
and should be **com.apple.broadcast-services-setupui**

The app will appear in the control center if the NSExtensionPointIdentifier is correct.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1012449/broadcast-extension-with-replaykit-xamarin-ios-not.html?childToView=1015704#answer-1015704)