# Xamarin iOS - Broadcast Upload Extension - how to invoke

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ios-extensions

Recently I added **Broadcast Upload Extension** to Xamarin.Forms project however I can't find a way how to invoke the extension and present it to the user from the container app.

How would I invoke the extension and present it to the user? Through OpenUrl and it's bundle identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to be invoked like this:

```
var bundle = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("Foo.iOS.ScreenShareExtensionUI", "appex", "PlugIns");

            RPScreenRecorder.SharedRecorder.StartRecording(true, error =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                    LogService.Log(error.LocalizedFailureReason, LogService.LogLevel.ERROR, "StartRecording");
            });
            RPBroadcastActivityViewController.LoadBroadcastActivityViewController(bundle.AbsoluteUrl.ToString(), (controller, error) =>
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(controller, true, null);

                RPBroadcastActivityViewController = controller;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is repeated somehow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741237/broadcast-extension-with-replaykit-xamarin-ios-not-working/73802422#73802422)

You need to double-check the `NSExtension` key.

The value of the `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` for BroadcastUploadExtension project is written as **com.apple.broadcast-services** by default
and should be **com.apple.broadcast-services-upload**

The value of the `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` for BroadcastUIExtension project is written as **com.apple.broadcast-services** by default
and should be **com.apple.broadcast-services-setupui**

[Refrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1012449/broadcast-extension-with-replaykit-xamarin-ios-not.html?childToView=1015704#answer-1015704)